# Are men allowed to wear Nylon in Islam, as long as they're inside normal socks?

Tags: halal-haram

Nylon is a silky, thermoplastic material. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nylon
So, is it allowed for men to wear anything made from Nylon, according to Islam? They make leggings, pantyhose, etc. from it. Is it allowed to wear them inside normal socks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is halal to wear. As long as it isn't natural silk.

From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nylon) you posted:

> Nylon was the first commercially successful synthetic thermoplastic polymer

And

> Nylon was intended to be a synthetic replacement for silk

And in accordance with the following [Fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/182349).

> وأما لبس الرجال للحرير الصناعي أو ما أشبهه من النايلون وغيره من الملبوسات الناعمة أو اللامعة... فإنه لا حرج فيه، والحرام هو الحرير الطبيعي فقط؛ فلا يجوز للرجل لبسه من غير ضرورة.
>
> About the men wearing artificial silk or its equivalent like Nylon and similar articles that are soft to the touch or sparkles, there is no issue in it. The Haram is natural silk only, for a man is not allowed to wear it without a need for it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. So, is Nylon real silk, or not, according to Wikipedia link I posted above?

Comment: @HüdaverdiAlperenDemirok It is not real, it is synthetic/artificial/man made.